# Unable to delete SharePoint Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, master-pages, delete-file

SharePoint by default has two master pages: Seattle and Oslo. The general rule is we should not modify these default master pages. If we need any customization, we should make their copy, make modification, upload to the Master Page Gallery and then use it. However a colleague of mine modified them directly and it screwed up some JavaScript functions. It impacted Performance Point Dashboard Designer and continuously started showing JavaScript errors.

In order to resolve the issue, I renamed the default master pages to Seattle_erroneous.masterpage and Oslo_erroneous.masterpage. I also renamed their respective .html files. I copied fresh copies of Seattle.masterpage and Oslo.masterpage from another web application, also their .html files, uploaded them to the Master Page Gallery, published their major version and started them referencing in subsites. It did solve JavaScript errors.

Now I want to clean up those erroneous master pages. When I try to delete them from the gallery, I get following error.

[image]

All the subsites inherit the working master page. Also I checked master page of each site one by one. All of them were referencing the working version. There was one site whose SharePoint Server Publishing feature was not enabled. I enabled it, and confirmed it was using the working version. I cannot delete the erroneous masterpages. It is referencing somewhere where I cannot see. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the solution shared by [here](http://magnussharepoint.blogspot.sg/2017/06/this-item-cannot-be-deleted-because-it.html).

1. My Issues with Test.html and Test.master
2. Go to Root Site, Site Settings->Look and Feel Section: Design
   Manager. Here the Master Page Html file can          be modified
   what changes are we make in .master file.
3. But Site Settings->Look and Feel Section: Design Manager ->Edit
   Master Pages Test.html was missing.(By default Seattle and Oslo will
   be appear)
4. Open the site collection through SharePoint Designer, Right click on
   Seattle.html file -> Select "Edit File in Advanced Mode" from
   context menu.
5. Seattle.html opens in a new Tab. Select all and copy the code.
6. Then Go to Test.html (Right Click) -> "Edit File in Advanced Mode".
   Opens in a new tab.
7. Replace the existing code in the "Test.html" by pasting the code
   from Seattle.html
8. Save the file (This is done in "Check In" status)
9. In the Browser, Go
       To Root Site, Site Settings -> Look and Feel: Design Manager ->
       "Edit Master Pages" in the left side.
10. Now here the Test.html file will appear. Delete this file

Comment: Sorry Lee! It did not work for me. In my case, the Test.html file was already visible. Even though replacing its code with default seattle.html did not help. :(